# Different Tesseract result for Mat and Pix

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, tesseract, leptonica

### Goal

Getting the same quality result when using OpenCV `Mat` as when using Leptonica `Pix` when doing OCR with Tesseract.

### Environment

C++17, OpenCV 3.4.1, Tesseract 3.05.01, Leptonica 1.74.4, Visual Studio Community 2017, Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

### Description

I'm working with Tesseract and OCR, and have found what I think is a peculiar behaviour.

This is my input image:
[image: Input image for the OCR]

And this is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace tesseract;

void opencvVariant(string titleFile);
void leptonicaVariant(const char* titleFile);

int main()
{
    cout << "Tesseract with OpenCV and Leptonica" << endl;

    const char* titleFile = "raptor-companion-2.jpg";
    opencvVariant(titleFile);
    leptonicaVariant(titleFile);

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void opencvVariant(string titleFile) {

    cout << endl << "OpenCV variant..." << endl;

    TessBaseAPI ocr;
    ocr.Init(NULL, "eng");
    Mat image = imread(titleFile);
    ocr.SetImage(image.data, image.cols, image.rows, 1, image.step);

    char* outText = ocr.GetUTF8Text();
    int confidence = ocr.MeanTextConf();

    cout << "Text: " << outText << endl;
    cout << "Confidence: " << confidence << endl;
}

void leptonicaVariant(const char* titleFile) {

    cout << endl << "Leptonica variant..." << endl;

    TessBaseAPI ocr;
    ocr.Init(NULL, "eng");
    Pix *image = pixRead(titleFile);
    ocr.SetImage(image);

    char* outText = ocr.GetUTF8Text();
    int confidence = ocr.MeanTextConf();

    cout << "Text: " << outText << endl;
    cout << "Confidence: " << confidence << endl;
}
```

The methods `opencvVariant` and `leptonicaVariant` is basically the same except that one is using the class `Mat` from OpenCV and the other `Pix` from Leptonica. Yet, the result is quite different.

```
OpenCV variant...
Text: Rapton


Confidence: 68

Leptonica variant...
Text: Raptor Companion


Confidence: 83
```

As one can see in the output above, the `Pix` variant gives a much better result than the `Mat` variant. Since my code relies heavily on OpenCV for the computer vision before the OCR its essential for me that the OCR works well with OpenCV and its' classes.

### Questions

- Why does `Pix` give a better result than `Mat`, and vice versa?
- How could the algorithm be changed to make the `Mat` variant as efficient as the `Pix` variant?

Comment: Can you try to replace your opencv setImage with `ocr.SetImage((uchar*)image.data, image.size().width, simageb.size().height, image.channels(), image.step1());`. By default imread would read colored image (even if it looks like black and white) so you're likely only giving tessereact `blue` channel of Mat

Comment: @DmitriiZ. I replaced it with `ocr.SetImage((uchar*)image.data, image.size().width, image.size().height, image.channels(), image.step1());` and now I get identical results!
You should write your comment as an answer! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenCV `imread` function by default reads image as colored, which means you get pixels as `BGRBGRBGR...`.
In your example you are assuming opencv image is grayscale, so there are 2 ways of fixing that:

1. Change your `SetImage` line according to number of channels in opencv image

   `ocr.SetImage((uchar*)image.data, image.size().width, simageb.size().height, image.channels(), image.step1());`
2. Convert your opencv image to grayscale with 1 channel

   `cv::cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2GRAY);`